# How to give file as argument when running CLion Debugger

Tags: cmake, clion

I have a c++ program that performs actions with `getline(cin,line)`. When I compile the .c file with g++, I usually just run

```
g++ lr.cc -o lr
./lr < text
```

Where `text` is a file.

However I'm getting an error and would like to debug where in the code the error is being generated (it's a `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
Aborted (core dumped)` error) but I can't seem to get CLion to compile the code and have the text file be a "argument".

I tried editing the arguments to `< test`, using the full path `< /path/to/text/` and also adding the file to the `set(SOURCE_FILES)` of the CMakeLists.txt.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out they don't support it (yet?). Used

```
std::ifstream in("/path/to/file/to/read");
std::cin.rdbuf(in.rdbuf());
```

at the beginning of my function that read `cin` and started the debugger